# sql server 2012: How do I deal with varbinary for @query variable in send_dbmail?

Tags: sql-server

My intent is to monitor the cdc process through a stored proc managed by a sql agent job. I am looking to see if I have captured any data since the last time the job executed. The IntervalHours represents how many hours since the last batch ran. Here is the code snippet that is the setup for the notify/not-notify decision:

```
  declare @FromLSN binary(10)
  declare @ToLSN binary(10)
  declare @BeginTime datetime 
  declare @EndTime datetime 
  declare @hasCurrentChanges int
  declare @SendLowFloorMessage bit

  select @BeginTime = dateadd(hh,-@IntervalHours,getdate())
  SET @EndTime = GETDATE();

  -- Map the time interval to a change data capture query range.
  SET @FromLSN = [myInstance].sys.fn_cdc_map_time_to_lsn('smallest greater
      than or equal', @BeginTime);

  SET @ToLSN =   [myInstance].sys.fn_cdc_map_time_to_lsn('largest less than 
      or equal', @EndTime);

  -- Return the count of the net changes occurring within the query window.
  SELECT @hasCurrentChanges = count(*) FROM
         [myInstance].cdc.fn_cdc_get_net_changes_dbo_CRM_POSTran(@FromLSN, @ToLSN, 
          'all');
```

-- Here is the decision --

```
   IF isnull(@hasCurrentChanges,0) <= @LowFloor
    begin 
     set @SendLowFloorMessage = 1;
    end
```

-- Here is the notification. This is where I would need the @qry to dub the value of @FromLSN and @ToLSN into the text of the query so it can execute. What do I need to cast the value to in order for this to succeed?

```
  DECLARE @bdy nvarchar(1000);
  DECLARE @sbj nvarchar(50)
  DECLARE @MailRecipients VARCHAR(50)
      DECLARE @qry nvarchar(max) 
  SET @MailRecipients = 'paula.ditallo@gmail.com'

  --Send email with results of long-running jobs
        EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
             @profile_name = @mailProfile
            ,@recipients = @MailRecipients
            ,@query = @qry
            ,@execute_query_database = 'InternalResource'
            ,@body = @bdy
            ,@subject = @sbj
            ,@attach_query_result_as_file = 1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you have a good handle on sp_send_dbmail and just do not know how to create a dynamic TSQL for the @query using the varbinary data types.  Here is one way to convert the data using the XML DOM.

Here is a reference to my website showing how to send an email with an attachment for 2008 R2.

http://craftydba.com/?p=1025.

This is almost the same for 2012 - Books On Line.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx.

The sample code below takes two hex number and converts them into a call to the cdc.fn_cdc_get_net_changes_.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522511.aspx

```
-- Sample data
DECLARE @from_lsn VARBINARY(10);
SET @from_lsn = 0x5BAA61E4C9B93F3F0682;

DECLARE @to_lsn VARBINARY(10);
SET @to_lsn = 0x5BAA61E4C9B93F3F0782;

-- Display the results
DECLARE @tsql VARCHAR(MAX);
SELECT @tsql =
'SELECT * FROM cdc.fn_cdc_get_net_changes_HR_Department(' + 
char(39) + '0x' + CAST('' AS XML).value('xs:hexBinary(sql:variable("@from_lsn"))', 'VARCHAR(20)') + char(39) + ',' +
char(39) + '0x' + CAST('' AS XML).value('xs:hexBinary(sql:variable("@to_lsn"))', 'VARCHAR(20)') + char(39) + + ',' +
char(39) + 'all' + char(39) +');';

-- Show the data
PRINT @tsql
```

Here is the output from the snippet.

```
SELECT * 
FROM  cdc.fn_cdc_get_net_changes_HR_Department
      ('0x5BAA61E4C9B93F3F0682','0x5BAA61E4C9B93F3F0782','all');
```

Comment: Thanks @CraftyDBA! :) I really appreciate the quick response.